# Using node.js / puppeteer to print form elements?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm accessing the web interface of a Ricoh printer.  I cannot identify the user name and password fields. Normally I "inspect" the form element and copy the "CSS Selector".  This method works for other forms but not this one.  Here is the "CSS Selector" which is copied:

`body > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(3) > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)`

Here is the user name field when inspected:

`<input name="userid_work" type="text" size="50" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;" autocomplete="off">`

I've tried various permutations of this, userid_work, etc, to no avail.  Here's basiclly what I'm trying to do?

`const USERNAME_SELECTOR = 'body > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(3) > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)';
await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
await page.keyboard.type(CREDS.username);`

So I was thinking of printing the form elements, and see what is returned.  Unless someone can tell me how this user name field should be referenced?

Tried various permutations of this form element.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to do (click or type)

So try this to click on the input:

```
await page.click('input[name="userid_work"]');
```

to type text into input:

```
await page.type('input[name="userid_work"]', text);
```

to click on the element using the javascript:

```
await page.$eval('input[name="userid_work"]', e => e.click);
```

to type into the element using the javascript:

```
await page.$eval('input[name="userid_work"]', e => e.value = 'text');
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I'm still getting a navigation error.  When I try this:


`
await page.goto('http://175.22.70.210/web/guest/en/websys/webArch/authForm.cgi');
await page.click('input[name="userid_work"]');
await page.type('input[name="userid_work"]', CREDS.username);
`

I receive this navigation error:

`
node ./ricoh-login-new.js
(node:23879) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.
`

Comment: What do you have in the `CREDS.username`?

Comment: Here is the credentials file read by the script, with the names changed:

`
module.exports = {
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'abracadabra'
}
`

Comment: try to add `await page.waitForSelector('input[name="userid_work"]')` function before click.

Comment: Thanks.  But when I try that I get the following error.  It's like it's hell bent on not recognizing this form element!

imeoutError: waiting for selector "input[name="userid_work"]" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

Comment: O, cool. So now we know that element is not loading and it fails due to waiting for the selector. Could you share the link? I want to try to reproduce and help you.

Comment: Can't share the link, it's behind a firewall.  This is the web interface for a Ricoh printer.